# PHP - Can I use a string as an object?

Tags: php, json

Let's assume I have the following JSON object

```
$object = 
{
  "recipe": {
    "apples": 5
    "flour": "2 lbs"
    "milk": "2 cartons"
  }
}
```

Now consider this function

```
private function get_quantity($ingredient) {
  $json = json_decode($object);
  return $json->recipe->{$ingredient};
}
```

If I pass `milk` to the function and want to get `2 cartons` as the output. Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Comment: well, did it work when you tried it? I'd also suggest as isset check `return (isset($json->recipe->$ingredient)) ? $json->recipe->$ingredient : null;`

Comment: @Scuzzy PHP isn't my native language (I'm working with C++, however my task-set requires PHP). I assumed that this might have been an improper format without trying it before-hand, and asked on stack right away. It appears stack has become my go-to for all my thoughts, before processing them myself.

Comment: It works, but you have a syntax error in your JSON: add the missing commas between the properties and you are set to go (and of course, JSON should be a string, so wrap it between single quotes)

Comment: @trincot Indeed, I'm aware, I just wrote it on the spot. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Then what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

**Note** `$object` is undefined in your function, you should pass it in as well:

```
private function get_quantity($object, $ingredient)
{
    $json = json_decode($object);

    return $json->recipe->{$ingredient};
}
```

Comment: Let's just assume I defined $object in my constructor, and referenced it via `$this`. Thanks for the answer, none-the-less :)

Comment: @user2581649 I'm confused why you even asked the question. The accepted answer is exactly the same as your proposed question with the exception of the `$object` which you've just said doesn't really factor into the question ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. The only problem with your code is the syntax. Try this:

```php
$object = '
{
  "recipe": {
    "apples": 5,
    "flour": "2 lbs",
    "milk": "2 cartons"
  }
}';
```

Notice I added commas, and sourrounded the JSON in quotes.

The method is well defined, assuming it can *see* `$object`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $object = 
    '{
      "recipe": {
        "apples": 5,
        "flour": "2 lbs",
        "milk": "2 cartons"
      }
    }';

    function get_quantity($object, $ingredient) {
      $json = json_decode($object);
      return $json->recipe->{$ingredient};
    }

    var_dump(get_quantity($object, 'milk'));
    ?>
```